# Создать шаблонный компонент

Tags: компоненты, c#-7.0, syncfusion, wasm

*веб-приложение `VisualStudio => C# => WASM`*

[в Блазор есть компоненты](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0) можно сравнить с тег-ом `html`(только персонализированный и расширенный). создав общий мы можем использовать потом на разных страницах

...следуя примеру я попыталась создать отдельный компонент,  помогите кто уже знаком

- в папке `Shared` создаю `разор` страницу

`Shared/Product.razor`

```
@typeparam IItem

<form>
   <fieldset>
      @if (ListGlobal != null)
         @foreach (var itemName in ListGlobal)
         {
            <div>
               <input type="checkbox" id="listId[intList]" name="item[i]" value="listId[intList]" />
               <label for="listId[intList]">@itemName</label>
            </div>
            intList++;         
         }
         <div>
            <button type="submit">✅</button>
            <button type="reset">❎</button>
         </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>

@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public IEnumerable<IItem>? ListGlobal { get; set; }
   public int intList { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

- затем на второй странице я использую компонент

```
<Product ListGlobal="GlobalListPiZZas">
</Product>
```

*в данном списке у меня тип объекта/модель. А как показать/добраться до свойства название пиццы,*
**что то вроде**

`GlobalListPiZZas.=>Model.=>NamePizza`  `foreach` ведь в компоненте, а в моем `родительском компоненте` только лист общий

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JE0tQ4tx0Nc